# Find the covariance of two jointly distributed RV's when you don't know the joint pmf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance

I have two correlated random variables, X and Y, and I am trying to find their covariance. I know: their individual expected values $\langle X \rangle$ and $\langle Y \rangle$ and their individual variances $\sigma^2_X$ and $\sigma^2_Y$. If the covariance is given as 
$cov(X,Y) = \langle XY \rangle -\langle X \rangle \langle Y \rangle$,
then I already know the second term but I have no idea how to compute the first term. I don't know the joint pmf. Do I need the joint pmf to calculate $\langle XY \rangle$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider two normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ each having mean zero and unit variance.
If they are independent, then their covariance is $$\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=0.$$
However, if $X=Y$ (i.e., the two variables are perfectly correlated), then $$\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=1.$$

What does this suggest?

Comment: This suggests that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$=1, but I can't see much beyond that, sorry!

Comment: But what does it suggest about the covariance? Is it uniquely determined by mean and variance?

Comment: I'm not sure because the bottom expression you wrote is the expression for the variance. So it states that the variance is equal to the variance. I'm not seeing how it can add any other constraint.

Comment: It's the expression for the covariance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Definition. Variance is just a special case of covariance when both inputs are equal.

Comment: Yes it is, but when X=Y it is also the expression for the variance:
$\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2$

Comment: I was trying to get you to come to the conclusion that you have insufficient information to determine the covariance.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will try to determine the joint probability mass function.

Comment: Put differently: the marginals do not characterize the joint distribution. Because $p_X\times p_Y$ has, by definition, the same marginals as $p_{XY}$.